# Sencha Touch Edit text of dynamically created divs

Tags: html, sencha-touch, dynamic

I have a function that creates divs automatically.

How can I edit the text of this divs when I click them?*

I have tried adding the property contenteditable and set it to true:

```
var divTag = document.createElement("div");
divTag.contenteditable="true"
```

but it is not working.

*The divs are draggable, I don't know if that affects what I need to do or not.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

I created a listener for a click for every div I create dynamically and I change the text there:

```
Ext.get('divID'+count).on('click', function(eventObj, elRef) {
        Ext.Msg.prompt('Text', 'Enter new text:', function(btn, text){
      if (btn == 'ok'){
          elRef.innerHTML = text;

});
```

divID + count is the id of my div, where count is a counter that increments every time I create a new div.